# Laravel "File Upload Error Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object"

Tags: php, laravel, upload

all.  I am trying to learn Laravel and I am working on uploading an image.  I get the following error:

"Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object"

I am using these packages:

```
"anahkiasen/former": "dev-master",
"intervention/image": "dev-master",
"intervention/imagecache": "2.*"
```

After using SO, I have verified the following are NOT contributing to the error above:

- multipart/form-data on form
- Upload file data exists
- The PHP.ini max_filesize  is way larger than the size of this small test file

My form is:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-horizontal" id="create_form" method="POST" action="/elements">

<div class="control-group"><label for="img[]" class="control-label">Upload Image</label><div class="controls"><input multiple="true" class="myclass" accept="image/gif|image/jpeg|image/png" id="img[]" type="file" name="img[]"></div></div>

<div class="form-actions"><input class="btn-large btn-primary btn" type="submit" value="Submit"> <input class="btn-large btn-inverse btn" type="reset" value="Reset"></div>

<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="B0AJ0Y5LMrMng6CsePeZfNSvRQ0KexowOGTK99Gm">
</form>
```

The code to generate the error is:

```
$image = Input::file('img');
$filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
print_($filename);
```

If I print out the object using:

print_r($image);

...then I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
        (
            [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
            [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => storageunit.jpg
            [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/jpeg
            [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 8734
            [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /tmp/php9AU1OE
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => php9AU1OE
        )

)
```

All of which looks correct to me, so I am stumped.

If anyone has any ideas as to what to try next, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Your error message is pretty clear, isn't it? `$image = Input::file('img');` is not returning what you think it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at what's printed out.  `$image` is an array of objects, not an object.  Try:

```
$filename = $image[0]->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: thx.  saw my mistake just after I posted the question.  See fix below.

Answer (score 1):

Doh!

"file" not "files"

```
{{
  Former::file('img')
  ->label('Upload Image')
  ->class('myclass')
  ->accept('gif', 'jpg', 'png');
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the only issue was the class file which the File Upload entity requires was missing.

I added this code and it worked,

use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;